# Manageable structure in Eloquent

Tags: eloquent, laravel-5.1

I need to use a `Photo` in several different places and cannot quite figure out what would be the best approach.

So basically, there is a gallery page on the website that shows a bunch of `Photos`. There is also a portfolio page, where each project has many `Photos`. There is a blog section too, and each blog has many `Photos`.

The common thing with these photos is that they have an `image_url` and a `caption`.

`Project` and `Blog` are Eloquent models and `Photo` model is a polymorphic model.

`Project` and `Blog` have:

```
public function photos()
{
    return $this->morphMany('App\Photo', 'imageable');
}
```

And the `Photo` model has:

```
public function imageable()
{
    return $this->morphTo();
}
```

This bit works fine. But my problem is that I want to attach this `Photo` model to the gallery as well. I'm thinking the two options I have, are:

1. Create a `Gallery` model, which will have just one entry, as the gallery is just one page. And the model would have the same `photos()` method as above.
2. When loading up the gallery page, retrieve all the photos that have `imageable_id` and `imageable_type` set to null. (This would mean that the photos that do not belong to neither `Project` nor `Blog`).

But I think there's a different, better approach that I cannot see. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I think both of the approaches you have are how most people would do it. You could make a new query scope for Photo to easily return the ones not attached a Project or Blog. This is what I would do.